# Adding item to target list from source list using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I am using csom to add items to target list from source list but I am not able to copy items of only title column.

```
srcContext = new ClientContext(mpObject.SourceSiteCollection.SiteURL);
                targetContext = new ClientContext(mpObject.TargetSiteCollection.SiteURL);

                List<Field> srcFieldCollections = new List<Field>();
                List srcList = srcContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                srcContext.Load(srcList);
                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";

                ListItemCollection srcListItemCollection = srcList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                srcContext.Load(srcListItemCollection);
                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
                ListItemCreationInformation targetItemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem targetListItem = targetList.AddItem(targetItemCreationInfo);

                foreach (ListItem sourceItem in srcListItemCollection)
                {

                    targetListItem["Title"] = "Title";

                }
                targetListItem.Update();
                targetContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But it works when I do it for other column. So am I missing anything there?

Comment: Please check internal name of target column.

Comment: Your code adds only ONE item to the target list, and then loops throw all source items, setting the title of the unique target item just added... Is this the entire code? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code. which will copy all the field values from source to destination.

```
srcContext = new ClientContext(mpObject.SourceSiteCollection.SiteURL);
                targetContext = new ClientContext(mpObject.TargetSiteCollection.SiteURL);

            List<Field> srcFieldCollections = new List<Field>();
            List srcList = srcContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            srcContext.Load(srcList);
            srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";

            ListItemCollection srcListItemCollection = srcList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            srcContext.Load(srcListItemCollection);
            srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
            ListItemCreationInformation targetItemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem targetListItem = targetList.AddItem(targetItemCreationInfo);

            foreach (ListItem sourceItem in srcListItemCollection)
            {
              foreach (Field field in sourceItem.Fields)
              {
                targetListItem[field.InternalName] = sourceItem[field.InternalName] ;
              }
              targetListItem["Title"] = sourceItem["Title"] ;
            }
            targetListItem.Update();
            targetContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Title column still remains empty, I have created a new list and then adding items, but not able to copy title column

Comment: make sure you have exact same column internal name as 'Title', Also do you have that column in AllItems view ?

Comment: yes internal name is same as when list is created , title column is created by default. and also yes this title column is available in all item view.